# Python pandas csv - can you read a list in a cell?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read a list in a csv file's cells for my plateformer using pygame.
The problem is, when I try to read the list saved in the cell, it interprets it as a str instead of a list. The list is something along the line of `[pygame.Rect(0, 750, 800, 50),...]`.
I want to put each lists into cells rather than columns because I have multiple lists like that per levels, with different lenght.

Is it possible to read a list inside a cell / interprete it as one, instead of having to fill the cells of the entire column with the data?

Comment: " when I try to read the list saved in the cell, it interprets it as a str instead of a list." of course, this will always happen wiht a csv. `pandas` will only try to interpret numeric columns,  datetime columns potentially, but everything else is assumed to be a string. Generally, working with lists inside your dataframe doesn't make a lot of sense to begin with

Comment: You can, of course, use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` to convert the strings to lists. But this is all generally something you'd wantto avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what @juanpa.arrivillaga said above in the comments but if you insist, you can try something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
import re
from io import StringIO


# pretend to be pygame.Rect
class MockRect:
    def __init__(self, left, top, width, height):
        self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height = left, top, width, height

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'pygame.Rect({self.left}, {self.top}, {self.width}, {self.height})'


# to change the string representation of our list of Rects to a string representation of a list of tuples
pattern = re.compile(r'pygame.Rect(\(\d+, \d+, \d+, \d+\))')


# to get back our list of Rects
def to_Rects(rects):
    s = pattern.sub(r'\g<1>', rects)
    arr = literal_eval(s)

    return [MockRect(*tup) for tup in arr]


# create our test DataFrame
d = {
    'id': [100, 101],
    'rects': [[MockRect(0, 0, 100, 50),
               MockRect(0, 50, 100, 50)],
              [MockRect(20, 0, 100, 50),
               MockRect(20, 20, 100, 50)]],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

# create our CSV
b = StringIO()
df.to_csv(b, index=False)
print(b.getvalue())

# read back our CSV
b.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(b)

# get back our list of Rects
df.rects = df.rects.apply(to_Rects)
print(df)
```